# Índices em colunas de chave primária

Tags: mysql, sql, índices, chave-primária

Sei que cada caso é um caso, e que não há regras prontas sobre a criação dos índices. No meu caso, considerando que a chave primaria de cada tabela do meu banco é utilizada nos `wheres` de minhas consultas ao banco, devo criar um índice para as mesmas? Ou o campo definido como chave primaria já eh considerado por padrão como um índice? Isso porque, no PhpMyAdmin, quando crio o índice na coluna já inserida como chave primaria, consta a mensagem que existe índices iguais para a mesma coluna, algo nesse sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No meu caso, considerando que a chave primaria de cada tabela do meu banco é utilizada nos wheres de minhas consultas ao banco, devo criar um índice para as mesmas?

A indicação da chave primária automaticamente cria um índice para ela. Não é necessário fazer mais nada.

Verifique se está criando algum índice desnecessário.

Comment: Obgd pelos esclarecimentos.